# Center or fix width of pagination links

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Anyone knows of a way to nicely center or fix width of pagination links?
Something like [this](http://www.artige.no/) would be ideal!

At the moment, I am using

> str_replace( $big, '%#%',
>   get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),           'format' => '?paged=%#%',           'current'
>   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),          'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,            'end_size' => 2,            'mid_size' => 3 ) );
>   ?>

So, when I'm at first page, my pagination links would like the following:
[image]
then on 4th page
[image]
then on 7th page
[image]
then on 2nd last page
[image]

In this example, I've made all the pagination links `float: left`.
Had I not done that, the "Next >>" link would be too far on the right side.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You simply need to use CSS to set the width of the links. Then all links are the same width and will not change the width of the pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @Scott and @shoaib akhunzada.
Unfortunately, your suggestions don't work.

I've written some Javascript to dynamically centered the group of the pagination links (which change from time to time) and the width of my page (which is fixed).

Problem is now solved!

Answer (score 0):

control width frome here not in ".pagination" class remove width there in pagination class

```
/* ur css */
.side {
    border: medium none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30px;     /* change this */
```